# Reflection and typeChecking for optionals

Tags: reflection, swift2, typechecking

Playing with reflections in swift 2.0 i'm trying to type check a child value.

**The problem:** each element of the children array in the Mirror of Any item is not optional, but his type can be optional... What happens is that of course i have the child value even if the value is nil

Maybe it is not clear so i put here some code to explain better.

For convenience i defined a subscript in a Mirror extension that fetches the child object with a given label

```
extension Mirror {
    public subscript(key: String)->Child?{
        var child = children.filter {
            var valid = false
            if let label = $0.label {
                valid = label == key
            }
            return valid
            }.last
        if child == nil,
            let superMirror = superclassMirror() {
                child = superMirror[key]
        }
        return child
    }
}
```

perfect, now let's say i have this class

```
class Rule: NSObject, AProtocol {
    var hello: String?
    var subRule: Rule?
}
```

Ok, now the problem

```
let aRule = Rule()
let mirroredRule = Mirror(reflecting:aRule)
if let child = mirroredRule["subRule"] {
     //child.value always exists
     //i can't do child.value is AProtocol? because child.value is not optional
     //child.value is AProtocol of course returns false
     //child.dynamicType is Optional(Rule)
     if let unwrapped = unwrap(child.value) where unwrapped is AProtocol {
         //This of course works only if child.value is not nil
         //so the unwrap function returns an unwrapped value
         //this is not a definitive solution
     }
}
```

child.value has not been initialized so it is nil, and i can't check his type using the unwrap function. I'm writing a deserializer so i need to check the var also if it is nil because in the dictionary that will be used for the deserialization it could be defined.

```
private func unwrap(subject: Any) -> Any? {
    var value: Any?
    let mirrored = Mirror(reflecting:subject)
    if mirrored.displayStyle != .Optional {
        value = subject
    } else if let firstChild = mirrored.children.first {
        value = firstChild.value
    }
    return value
}
```

I hope the problem is clear. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I would recommend filing a bug report for it.  It's definitely broken behavior IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40927739/1202867), I recommend using `if case Optional<Any>.some(_)`.

I did something recently to make sure I have at least one optional set on my struct. You can paste into playgrounds:

```
struct ErrorResponse: Codable {
    let message: String?
    let authorizationException: [String: String]?
    let validationException: String?
    let generalException: String?

    var isValid: Bool {
        var hasAtLeastOneNonNilErrorValue = false
        Mirror(reflecting: self).children.forEach {
            if case Optional<Any>.some(_) = $0.value {
                hasAtLeastOneNonNilErrorValue = true
            }
        }
        return hasAtLeastOneNonNilErrorValue
    }
}

let errorTest = ErrorResponse(message: "some message", authorizationException: nil, validationException: nil, generalException: nil)
let errorTest2 = ErrorResponse(message: nil, authorizationException: nil, validationException: nil, generalException: nil)

print("is valid: \(errorTest.isValid)")  //is valid: true
print("is valid: \(errorTest2.isValid)") //is valid: false
```