# How do I cast an Any value with nil in it to a Any?

Tags: swift, reflection

I am using reflection to try to check if a struct has a nil value.

```
struct MyStruct {
    let myString: String?
}

let properties = Mirror(reflecting: MyStruct(myString: nil)).children.filter { $0.label != nil }

for property in properties {
    if property.value == nil { // value has type "Any" will always fail.
        print("property \(property.label!) is nil")
    }
}
```

How do I cast the Any type to Any?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To simply check for `nil` content in the property value wrapped in an `Any`, you *can*, contrary to methods described in the other answers, actually work your way around casting/binding/checking to a concrete non-`Any` type by directly applying pattern matching to `Optional<Any>.none` or `Optional<Any>.some(...)`.

Example setup (different members types: we don't want to annotate all these different types simply for reflection checking for `nil` content)

```
struct MyStruct {
    let myString: String?
    let myInt: Int?
    let myDouble: Double?
    // ...
    init(_ myString: String?, _ myInt: Int?, _ myDouble: Double?) {
        self.myString = myString
        self.myInt = myInt
        self.myDouble = myDouble
    }
}
```

**Simple logging: Extracting property names of `nil` valued properties**

Pattern matching to `Optional<Any>.none`, if you simply want to log info on `nil` valued entities:

```
for case (let label as String, Optional<Any>.none) in 
    Mirror(reflecting: MyStruct("foo", nil, 4.2)).children {
    print("property \(label) is nil")
}
/* property myInt is nil */
```

**Slightly more detailed logging: for `nil` as well as non-`nil` valued properties**

Pattern matching to `Optional<Any>.some(...)`, in case you want more detailed logging (the binded `x` value below corresponds to your guaranteed non-`nil` `Any` instance)

```
for property in Mirror(reflecting: MyStruct("foo", nil, 4.2)).children {
    if let label = property.label {
        if case Optional<Any>.some(let x) = property.value {
            print("property \(label) is not nil (value: \(x))")
        }
        else {
            print("property \(label) is nil")
        }
    }
}
/* property myString is not nil (value: foo)
   property myInt is nil
   property myDouble is not nil (value: 4.2) */
```

Or, the latter using a `switch` case instead:

```
for property in Mirror(reflecting: MyStruct("foo", nil, 4.2)).children {
    switch(property) {
        case (let label as String, Optional<Any>.some(let x)): 
            print("property \(label) is not nil (value: \(x))")
        case (let label as String, _): print("property \(label) is nil")
        default: ()
    }
}
/* property myString is not nil (value: foo)
   property myInt is nil
   property myDouble is not nil (value: 4.2) */
```

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid the casting to `String` with `String(describing: value)` or `value as? String` by testing its type directly.

```
for (label, value) in properties {
  if !(value is String) {
    print("Property \(label!) is nil")
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not cast `Any` to `Any?` type. Unfortunately `Any` cannot be compared to `nil` because it actually is holding the enum `Optional<T>` which holds `nil`.

Instead of trying to cast `Any` to an optional type `Any?`, better cast the optional type that is already in `Any` to `String` type. You should use an optional binding with a type casting:

```
for property in properties {
    if let value = property.value as? String {
        print ("property \(property.label!) is not nil");
    } else {
        print ("property \(property.label!) is nil");
    }
}
```

`Any` type can hold anything, including optionals because they are in fact an enum type (`Optional<T>`) which evaluates `case none` and `case some(T)`. So `nil` is in fact one of those cases:

```
nil == Optional<T>.none // Always returns true
```

So instead of evaluating `Any` type to `nil` it is better to try an optional binding. If it succeeds it doesn't have `nil`, if it doesn't it indeed has `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a best answer. But it can solve your problem.

As prodevmx said,

nil == Optional.none // Always returns true

So you can't just check

```
if let value = property.value as? Any  {
}
```

This condition always passes and "Any" it's not an optional value.

Please use this function

```
func checkAnyContainsNil(object : Any) -> Bool {
    let value = "\(object)"
    if value == "nil" {
       return true
    }
    return false
 }
```

Converting the object to nil string and check whether the string is nil